# Keep auto created input with jquery after reload and show the data in it from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cookies

I am new to web development and javascript and jquery 
I am working in auto created dynamic input field as much as user want and save that list in database , I already did that . 
but I am facing 3 problem with that :

1. if the user want to reload the page I lose the already created list.
2. I had to show the same list from database in the same fields for update and 
   I don't know how to do it !!
3. The counter of the list works fine if i delete a row it decrement in right 
   way , but if i want to delete for example number 4 in list from 8 row the 
   counter doesn't work properly .

here is the list : 
[image]

and here is the html code :

```
<div id="initRow" class="row">
       <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-md-1">
       <input class="form-control no-border text-center" id="count" value="1" readonly style="background-color:#FFFFFF">  
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="AssistantFactorsToSuccessProject[]" id="AssistantFactorsToSuccessProject" placeholder="Value" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="control-label"><a class="rowDelete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></a></label>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

and here is the javascript code :

```
var $counter = document.getElementById('count');
function addRow(section, initRow) {
    var counter = 1;
    var newRow = initRow.clone().removeAttr('id').addClass('new').insertBefore(initRow),
        deleteRow = $('');

    newRow.on('click', 'a.rowDelete', function() {
            removeRow(newRow);
        })
        .slideDown(300, function() {
            $(this)
                .find('input').focus();

        })

}

function removeRow(newRow) {
    newRow
        .slideUp(200, function() {
            $(this)
                .next('div:not(#initRow)')
                    .find('input').focus()
                    .end()
                .end()
                .remove();
                 $counter.value = parseInt($counter.value) - 1;
        });
}
 $("#FeasibiltyStudyDate").val( moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD') );

$(function () {

    var initRow = $('#initRow'),
        section = initRow.parent('section');

    initRow.on('focus', 'input', function() {
        addRow(section, initRow);
         $counter.value = parseInt($counter.value) + 1;
         }
    });
});
```

and here is how I save it as array in db :

```
 for ($i=0;$i<count($_POST['AssistantFactorsToSuccessProject']);$i++) {

        $f = implode("</br>", $_POST['AssistantFactorsToSuccessProject']);
        $AssistantFactorsToSuccessProject = $f;

}
```

Comment: "if the user want to reload the page I lose the already created list.". yep that's how browsers work. If the user presses refresh without saving their work, that's their problem not yours.

Answer (score 0):

answers for the mentioned points in the query.

1)if the user want to reload the page I lose the already created list.

Your not storing the data in database so on page refresh client side data will be cleared.

2)I had to show the same list from database in the same fields for update and I don't know how to do it !!

through ajax or form submit store the data in database.
refer to the below link: https://www.formget.com/insert-data-in-database-using-php/

3)The counter of the list works fine if i delete a row it decrement in right way , but if i want to delete for example number 4 in list from 8 row the counter doesn't work properly .

for delete you have to delete by id.
like. $('itemid').remove(); // it will remove html entity of that id.